# Config option to permanently disable "window always in foreground" mode in MobaXTerm

Tags: mobaxterm

The MobaXterm release notes for v9.4 say the following:

```
Improvement: added a "Stay on top" button for fullscreen windows 
   in order to toggle "window always in foreground" mode
```

I want to disable this window always in foreground mode, and my hunch is that there should be an undocumented flag that I can set in the `MobaXterm.ini` file to achieve that effect. Does anyone know of such a flag? It's definitely not showing up on google.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

A bar shows up when you mouse over the top of the window in fullscreen mode. One of the buttons on this bar is "Stay on top", which you can toggle by clicking on it.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Is there a way to permanently configure this option? Instead of toggling this every time we go fullscreen.

Comment: Not that I know of.

Comment: I had the same issue and it is annoying that each time I need to click it to disable the always on top.

Answer (score 1):

I too was looking to toggle that setting off by default, but it appears there is no way to do that.

To not have to click the button myself everytime (which I tend to forget) I created this short [AutoHotKey (AHK)](https://www.autohotkey.com/) function:

```
; Maximize MobaxTerm to fullscreen without stay on top
#IfWinActive, ahk_exe MobaXterm.exe
F11::
    Send {F11}
    Sleep 750
    SetControlDelay -1
    ControlClick, X150 Y10, ahk_class TFormDetachedTab,,,, NA
    return
#IfWinActive
```

When <kbd>F11</kbd> is pressed (the shortcut to make a tab fullscreen) AHK checks if MobaXterm is the active window. If it is, it presses <kbd>F11</kbd>, waits 750 ms, removes the [click delay](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/SetControlDelay.htm) and presses the button at window coordinates (150, 10) which is the "Stay on top" toggle.

The coordinates (150, 10) might differ in your case (likely dependent on screen resolution), so use AHK WindowSpy to identify the correct position.

Also note that the 750 ms delay is something that might need tweaking. The toolbar with the button needs to be visible to be clicked, and this delay is short enough for the toolbar to still be visible before auto-hiding.

A longer delay (e.g. 1000 ms) meant that the toolbar was already hidden.
A shorter delay (e.g. 300 ms) resulted in the toolbar not being available yet.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why I use mobaxterm is its convinience for x11 forwarding.   Now that windows terminal support x11, I think using it may be better, which seems more lightwight.
https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5351#issuecomment-946985266

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't directly answer the question.